# Export large geometry from Aurora to csv and load to redshift

Tags: csv, geometry, export, amazon-redshift, amazon-aurora

Hi expert programmers,

I need to export a table that contains a geometry column holding large data set from Aurora as csv and then load to redshift using copy command.
Export data from another table that also contains a geometry column holding smaller data set works no problem with above approach.

The issue i found with bigger geometry is the data was split into 2 or more lines, which I dont seem to get around then loading such data using copy command in redshift.

Here are what I have tried using dbeaver and pgAdmin

1. change delimiter from "," to "|" or tab then export the csv is still splitting the geometry up.
2. change csv to json, however redshift only accept geometry load using csv, text or shapefile.
3. tried to convert geometry to EWKT[1] and then export using different delimiter, the final csv is still splitting up the geometry data.
4. tried to export table with text, but a file that is 70M turns out to be 1.9G. not very preferable of this one

As of 2023-08-11
After checking the length of the cell that's been broken in the exported csv using dbeaver/pgAdmin. They are less than the maximum character length that a excel cell can hold 32,767 characters[2].I found it's associated with the exporting tool.

So this morning I used python connect to aurora postgres to export and and save query geometry results in geometry format (binaries) as a dataframe and then saved it in csv.

Now there is what i found:

1. the previous shorter (<32,767) ones are perfectly in a cell now.
2. how about the longer ones that are >32,767? It looks like csv is no longer an option for storing geometry that are longer than 32,767.
3. tried to convert geometry into ewkt format as aws documentation [1] mentioned. it's still longer than 32,767.

So my question is what would you recommend to transfer a small amount of spatial data containing large geometry from aurora to redshift in different account in different VPC network without have to think about other options that I've been reading, federal queries etc. at this time point.

as this is part of a POC and we wanted to get this one done asap, so a fastest approach better.

having be struggling this for 2 days and looking forward for some fresh input.

Thank you so much.

[1]https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-usage_notes-spatial-data.html
[2]https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3

Answer (score 0):

I reached out to AWS support just now through my wonderful manager. DMS is what is recommended for this case. Just wanted to share the answer here.